# How to create an NSArray of NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to sort an array of NSDictionaries into an alphabatised array of arrays based of one of the NSDictionary `valueForKey:` first letters

effectively I want something that looks a little something like this

```
Array A // contains NSDictionaies with keyvalue MAF strings starting with A
 NSDictionary1
 NSDictionary2
 NSDictionary3
Array B // contains NSDictionaies with keyvalue MAF strings starting with B
 NSDictionary1
 NSDictionary2
 NSDictionary3
Array C // contains NSDictionaies with keyvalue MAF strings starting with C
 NSDictionary1
 NSDictionary2
 NSDictionary3
etc
```

So I have an array of Letters and inside each letter array I would like to have an Array of NSDictionary values that keyValue MAFs first letter should match.

So far I have an array of dictionaries that I have sorted like so

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"MAF"
                                                      ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        sortedDictionaryArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; // use this in cellforrow: and didselectrow:

        NSLog(@"%@", sortedDictionaryArray); // this gives me a sorted array of NSdictionaries based off their MAF keyvalue.
```

This is what the NSDicitonary looks like

```
HADM = 1;
ISLOT = 0;
ISVERT = 0;
MAF = "Yazot"; // keyvalue I am trying to work with.
```

Then I get stuck, I am not sure where to go from here. if anyone could help me understand how to create an NSArray of NSArrays NSDictionaries that would be great! hopefully I have explained what I am trying to do correctly, if you need any more details just let me know and I will supply.

Comment: What does the data look like initially? Just a bunch of dictionaries in a single array?

Comment: yep, sorted alphabetically by the string in the MAF keyvalue of the NSDictionary Object.

Comment: Do they need to be sorted in the final arrays? If so, then why not enumerate the initial list, put them in each lettered array, and then sort each of those letter arrays separately? If not, then just enumerate and don't do the last sort.

Comment: they need to be sorted in their final instance.. where they are in the array of arrays... okay going to look up enumerate now and see what I can do.

Comment: The issue I have is not knowing the code to check the dictionaries keyvalue... or something like that. man this is killing me lol

Comment: I have created an array of firstletters of MAF then I am trying to set up an enumeration like this 'for (NSString *sectionLetterArray in [[sortedDictionaryArray valueForKey:@"MAF"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]){' but obviously thats not working.. this is the trouble I am having atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will first sort your array of dictionaries by using the objects assigned to the key `@"MAF"`. Than it will create a new Dictionary where it will add a mutable array for each first letter of that string and add the object to it.

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"MAF": @"Yazot"}, @{@"MAF": @"Lorem"},@{@"MAF": @"Ipsum"}, @{@"MAF": @"Laura"},@{@"MAF": @"Isit"}];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    return [obj1[@"MAF"] compare:obj2[@"MAF"]];
}];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *dict in sortedArray) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [dict[@"MAF"] substringToIndex:1];

    if(![[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:firstLetter])
        dictionary[firstLetter] = [NSMutableArray array];

    [dictionary[firstLetter] addObject:dict];

}
```

---

if you need case insensitive string handling, "L" and "l" should be put into the same array, do

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"MAF": @"Yazot"}, @{@"MAF": @"Lorem"},@{@"MAF": @"Ipsum"}, @{@"MAF": @"Laura"},@{@"MAF": @"Isit"}];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    return [obj1[@"MAF"] caseInsensitiveCompare:obj2[@"MAF"]];
}];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *dict in sortedArray) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [dict[@"MAF"] substringToIndex:1];
    firstLetter = [firstLetter lowercaseString];
    if(![[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:firstLetter])
        dictionary[firstLetter] = [NSMutableArray array];

    [dictionary[firstLetter] addObject:dict];

}
```

---

dictionary results in

```
{
    i =     (
                {
            MAF = Ipsum;
        },
                {
            MAF = Isit;
        }
    );
    l =     (
                {
            MAF = Laura;
        },
                {
            MAF = Lorem;
        }
    );
    y =     (
                {
            MAF = Yazot;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: okay cool, will give this ago now and will get back to you with my results :) thank you

Comment: worked perfectly... thanks very much for your help! going to read over this some more investigate it and try to learn it for myself... clearly I still have some learning to do :P

Answer (score 1):

We can start by creating a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictsForFirstLetter = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayData) {
    NSString *dictMAF = dict[@"MAF"];
    NSString *firstLetter = [[dictMAF substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
    NSMutableArray *dicts = dictsForFirstLetter[firstLetter];
    if (!dicts) {
        dicts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        dictsForFirstLetter[firstLetter] = dicts;
    }
    [dicts addObject:dict];
}
```

Then you can retrieve the array of dictionaries by the first letter of their MAF value:

```
NSArray *dicts = dictsForFirstLetter[@"Y"];
```

---

To get an alphabetized array from this, you can sort the dictionary's keys and enumerate over them:

```
NSMutableArray *alphabetizedDicts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *firstLetters = [dictsForFirstLetter allKeys];
NSArray *sortedFirstLetters = [firstLetters sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

for (NSString *firstLetter in sortedFirstLetters) {
    NSArray *dicts = dictsForFirstLetter[firstLetter];
    [alphabetizedDicts addObject:dicts];
}
```